# GAE Python self.request.get_all not returning selected value

Tags: python, google-app-engine, select

I am trying to get a value out of a SELECT tag.

My HTML is

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="acadYear">Academic Year:</label>
  <select id="acadYear" name"acadYear">
    <option value="2017-18">This Academic Year</option>
    <option value="2018-19">Next Academic Year</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

My python code to get this value is

```
acadYear=self.request.get('acadYear')
```

This doesn't return anything. When I try

```
acadYear=self.request.get_all('acadYear')
```

throws an error

```
BadValueError: Expected string, got []
```

What's happening? Any clues?

**MORE DETAILS**

The Entity

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb

class Allocation(ndb.Model):
  acadYear = ndb.StringProperty()
  branch = ndb.StringProperty()
  semester = ndb.StringProperty()
  subjectCode = ndb.StringProperty()
  subjectName = ndb.StringProperty()
  facultyId = ndb.StringProperty()
  facultyName = ndb.StringProperty()
  choiceNumber = ndb.StringProperty()
  status = ndb.StringProperty()
  createdOn = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)

  @classmethod
  def faculty_query(cls, parent_key):
    return cls.query(ancestor=parent_key).order(-cls.createdOn)
```

**HTML Code to Receive Data**

```
    <form action="" method="post">
      <legend>Mention Your New Preferences Here</legend>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="acadYear">Academic Year:</label>
        <select id="acadYear" name="acadYear">
          <option value="2017-18">This Academic Year</option>
          <option value="2018-19">Next Academic Year</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="branch">Branch:</label>
        <input type="text" id="branch" name"branch" value="CSE or ISE or MCA">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="semester">Semester:</label>
        <input type="text" id="semester" name="semester" value="From 1 to 8"/>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="choiceNumber">Choice#:</label>
        <input type="text" id="choiceNumber" name="choiceNumber" value="1,2,3"/>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="subjectCode">Subject Code:</label>
        <input type="text" id="subjectCode" name="subjectCode" value="Example: 10CS43"/>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="subjectName">Subject Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="subjectName" name="subjectName" value="Example: Design and Analysis of Algorithms"/>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit">Save Preference</button>
      </div>
    </form>
```

**Python Handler**

## MainHandler Class

```
class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def _render_template(self, template_name, context=None):
        if context is None:
            context = {}
    # Get the logged in user        
    user = users.get_current_user()
    ancestor_key = ndb.Key("User", user.nickname())
    qry = Allocation.faculty_query(ancestor_key)
    context['allocs'] = qry.fetch()

    template = jinja_env.get_template(template_name)
    return template.render(context)

@ndb.transactional
def _create_alloc(self, user):
   alloc = Allocation(parent=ndb.Key("User", user.nickname()),
        acadYear=self.request.get_all('acadYear'),
        branch=self.request.get('branch'),
        semester=self.request.get('semester'),
        subjectCode=self.request.get('subjectCode'),
        subjectName=self.request.get('subjectName'),
        facultyId=user.user_id(),
        facultyName=user.nickname(),
        choiceNumber=self.request.get('choiceNumber'),
        status='Requested')
   alloc.put()

def get(self):
    user = users.get_current_user()
    if user is not None:
        logout_url = users.create_logout_url(self.request.uri)
        template_context = {
            'user': user.nickname(),
            'logout_url': logout_url,
        }
        self.response.out.write(
            self._render_template('main.html', template_context))
    else:
        login_url = users.create_login_url(self.request.uri)
        self.redirect(login_url)

def post(self):
    user = users.get_current_user()
    if user is None:
        self.error(401)

    self._create_alloc(user)

    logout_url = users.create_logout_url(self.request.uri)
    template_context = {
        'user': user.nickname(),
        'logout_url': logout_url,
    }
    self.response.out.write(
        self._render_template('main.html', template_context))
```

`acadYear=self.request.get_all('acadYear')` returns a `list` - apparently in `Unicode` - which need to become `string` for `putting` into data store.

I have tried the following

(1) Use an intermediate variable = does not work. 
(2) Encoding to `UTF-8` - can't because the `list` does not have an `encode` method.
(3) I don't know which element would be chosen `[0]` or `[1]`. Hence I can't try
`acadYear=self.request.get_all('acadYear')[0].encode('UTF-8')`.

Such a simple thing - but - why it had to be so complex!

Any help is appreciated. I am losing face before kids.

Comment: you have to use html parser library like BeautifulSoup , you can install it by **pip install bs4**

Comment: @Stack no you don't. Why do you think that would solve the problem?

Comment: @MaheshaTechie please show the full handler function, and the context of that HTML code - is it inside  a `form` element?

Comment: After I sorted out a missing `</div>`, the error updated itself to `BadValueError: Expected string, got [u'2017-18']`

Comment: There is no issue on the datastore side. It is receiving multiple values without the `repeated` option. The problem is between the UI side and Python program wherein Python is reading UI and putting it to datastore. The exact problem `request.get` is not getting the selected value from `SELECT` tag.

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo in this line:

```
<select id="acadYear" name"acadYear">
```

You need to add an "=" after "name".  Because of this typo, your browser is not sending the data for the select field.